# How does a foreign resident of the UK declare that she got married in her home country?

Tags: united-kingdom, marriage

My fiance and I recently got married in our home country (Egypt). She has been living and working in the UK for about a year now while I live in Germany. When she entered the UK, she was single.

Does she have to report to the authorities now that she got married? if yes, where should she go or what should she do?

Note that we are not interested in any sort of dependent visa for me, I am just asking about the procedure of declaring marriage in the UK, when the person in question is a foreigner who got married abroad.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think she has to declare that she is married to anyone. The only things to consider:

1. It would be very wise if she had papers in her possession that prove she is married to you if needed. For example, if you end up in hospital for some reason, she might not have the right to visit you unless she can prove she is your wife (could be bad if your relatives dislike her or don't even know of the marriage).
2. If she would have legal advantages by being married or not being married, lying about it could get her into trouble. For example, if she decides to marry someone in the UK, and the UK registry office doesn't know about your marriage and marry her, that would be a crime.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any master notification, but she needs to look at each of her legally significant relationships.

If her visa requires notification of any significant change in circumstances, she may need to report the marriage there. That may be a basis for a separate question that should include the visa type.

It may be worth consulting her local Citizens Advice Bureau, for any notifications she needs to do in the UK.

If she has a will and/or insurance policies with a named beneficiary she should review them.

Comment: No visa in the UK requires such notification nor is any immigrant required to make such a declaration. The Citizens Advice Bureau will simply confirm that. If applying for entry into the UK, or for leave to remain in the UK, they may be asked then, otherwise that's it.

Comment: If she has a will that was made under English and Welsh law, and it was not explictily made "in contemplation of the marriage", it has been invalidated by the marriage.  I do not believe insurance companies need to be notified about marrying the named beneficiary (if some *other* individual is named, it might be worth confirming that this is intended to continue).

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to declare the marriage.

Comment: Is there no official context in which she would have been asked for her marital status, and might need to declare the change?  In the US, for example, income tax depends on marital status, so someone in this situation would have to declare the change on the next income tax return by selecting the appropriate status and calculating tax accordingly. There's no general requirement to submit evidence to support the declaration of marital status, however; that the declaration is made under penalty of perjury is sufficient. I suppose the same might be true in the UK.

Comment: @phoog, Someone may be asked that as part of a declaration when entering the country, but there is no requirement for notification at all. And U.S. taxes do not depend on maritial status. If a resident taxpayer so chooses, they can file as married or single, but there is no requirement that they file as married if they indeed are so. There is no 'declaration of marital status' in the UK. If it comes up at a relevant context, then it is considered. In the United States, the rules are different. The newlywed *MUST* notify the government of their 'change of status' as soon as possible.

Comment: @phoog, Someone may be asked when applying for a new visa in the country as well, but again, no notification required at all.

Comment: I should note that the tax requirements for American expats are quite (unfairly) different, but this is not question about taxes.

Comment: Do you have a source to support your claim that a married US taxpayer can file as single if they choose?  It certainly does not agree with the text of [the instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf).  Furthermore, if it were true, only a fool would ever file as "married filing separately."  Also, what US government body is a newlywed supposed to notify of change of status as soon as possible?  I need to know, since I never made such a notification when I got married seven years ago.

Comment: @phoog, It seems the laws have changed since I've been away. There are now two status: Married Filing Jointly and Married Filing Separately. And if you look at the instructions, there are several valid situations where it is more appropriate to file separately. Also, it's not always better to file Jointly, especially for certain types of deductions and if there are certain debts. I can't find any rules regarding a requirement to report a change of circumstances. It was a long time ago, and I remember distinctly thining, "That's draconian!" Again, I'm a bit out of touch, it seems, with US law.

Comment: When did you last file US taxes?  Those statuses both existed when I filed my first tax return in 1981 or thereabouts.  [In fact they both existed in 1961 when the filing status checkboxes first appeared on form 1040.](http://www.taxhistory.org/www/website.nsf/Web/1040TaxForms?OpenDocument)

Comment: Is there a listing for 1040A on that site? Poked around a bit, couldn't see it.

Comment: I don't see one, but you can look them up [on the IRS site](https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?value=1040-A&criteria=formNumber&submitSearch=Find).

Comment: There may be things like being able to visit your spouse in a hospital as the "next of kin". For inheritance law, being married will make a difference. But I don't think there's anyone to notify, you just might have to have evidence when needed. For example if your husband's third degree cousin wants to inherit everything when the husband dies without a will, you'd have to show your marriage certificate and he gets nothing.

Comment: 1040A was discontinued for tax year 2018 and later, I learned a moment ago.